How to register WAR project to Netflix's Eureka Server?
I have 2 separate WAR projects made using Jakarta EE 11, running on 8080 & 8081 on Wildfly.
Then I have Netflix's Eureka-Server running on 8761 on Tomcat(Spring Boot Project).
How do I make register, these Wildfly running projects on Eureka.
In Spring it is easy, we just need to add spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client starter, to the project we want to be registered in Eureka-Server then add the annotation @EnableDiscoveryClient in main class, and add the following in application.yml
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

But how to do this when client projects aren't Spring Boot JAR type, here they are WAR type.
Tried finding tutorials but couldn't find any, all of them demoing on how to do that in Spring Boot.
Is it even possible?

You can deploy jar on the wildfly as well. There is no hard constraint that war needs to be only deployed.

eureka/eureka-examples
(https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/tree/master/eureka-examples) , very old example , no spring or spring boot, just pure Tomcat war.

First of all, it's impossible to integrate Spring's Eureka Client  with Jakarta EE application whether it's jar or war.
If it's possible with hacky some code also, then I will not recommend to do it because it would be difficult to maintain in the long run.
I guess you have a JAX-RS/Jersey  application developed with Jakarta EE .
If I assume that you have a JAX-RS/Jersey application developed with Jakarta EE, the same JAX-RS/Jersey application can be re-written with Spring also via Spring Boot Jersey Library. This will make your life easier.
You can use spring-boot-starter-jersey to develop Spring based JAX-RS/Jersey standalone application (both jar/war type is supported) and use spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client with that application.
There are a lot of examples and tutorials with spring-boot-starter-jersey available online.
See if this helps.
